# Не получается поменять иконку MenuItem при нажатии на нее

Tags: java, android, menu

Есть код:

```
switch (id) {
            case R.id.favorite:
                Intent giveIntent = getIntent();
                String contentUrl = giveIntent.getStringExtra("URL_KEY");
                String contentTitle = giveIntent.getStringExtra("TITLE_KEY");
                String contentDate = giveIntent.getStringExtra("DATE_KEY");
                String contentCategory = giveIntent.getStringExtra("CATEGORY_KEY");
                Favorites.favoritNews.add(new NewsClass(
                        contentTitle,
                        contentDate,
                        contentUrl,
                        contentCategory)
                );
                Toast.makeText(this, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MenuItem favButton = findViewById(R.id.favorite);
                favButton.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);
                break;
```

При нажатии на пункт меню приложение крашится с сообщением:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem
```

Понимаю, что проблема именно в команде смены иконки пункта меню favorite на R.drawable.ic_action_favdark.

Как исправить это недоразумение?

Comment: Проблема, исходя из сообщения, в `MenuItem favButton = findViewById(R.id.favorite);`. Предполагаю, что приведенный Вами кусочек кода из метода `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {`, тогда почему бы сразу не использовать `item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);`?

Comment: Точно, сработало. Видимо, я решил просто все усложнить. Спасибо!